# Magento 2.2.7 NGinx Error

Tags: magento2, error, php-7, nginx

Hello as you can see in the title:

- I have nginx installed it is working fine
- PHP 7.1
- Installed PHP-XML
- Installed PHP-DOM
  But still getting this problem when i for example want to clear cache.

pelase Help meeeee

---

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:384
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('__construct('_createConfigMerger('Magento\\Framewo...', '_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator))
#4 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(275): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('primary')
#5 /var/www/magento/vend in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 384
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install php-dom

Comment: restarted fpm? is module available?